# Isomorphism between $B_2$ and $C_2$

Tags: lie-algebras

> For small values of $l$, isomorphisms occur among certain of the classical algebras. Show that $B_2$ is isomorphic to $C_2$.

Well, both $B_2$ and $C_2$ have dimension $10$. $B_2$ consists of $5\times 5$ matrices, while $C_2$ consists of $4\times 4$ matrices. It seems to take too much work to exhibit an explicit isomorphism, and then computing to show that $\phi([x,y])=[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$, where $[x,y]=xy-yx$. How can we show that the two algebras are isomorphic?

Comment: if you have access to a computer algebra system, you can just pick your bases and compute the various commutators. then you can try to see how to cook up a lie algebra isomorphism

Comment: @exitingcorpse I don't have a computer algebra system. Is there a way to show the isomorphism by hand?

Comment: Please check the answer in [here][1] for a basis-independent proof.


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/why-lie-algebras-of-type-b-2-and-c-2-are-isomorphic